# Adding ggplot code chunk to RMarkdown breaks HTML tabset

Tags: r, ggplot2, tabs, r-markdown

Newish R programmer here and new to SO...

I have an RMarkdown doc where I've created tabs.

For some reason, when I try to knit, the chunks with ggplot seem to break the tabset code, because when I omit those chunks, the doc appears as it should.

When the ggplot code include = FALSE, the tabs are included, but the below code appears to break the tabs.  Any ideas for workarounds?  Is this a bug, or my novice-ness?  Thanks in advance...

````
## Options {.tabset .tabset-pills}

```{r Barplot, include=TRUE,echo=FALSE}

barplot_group_count <- ggplot(data=group_count, aes(x=Group, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Count of Groups According to PSA Attributes") +
  coord_flip()

barplot_group_count
```
````

Comment: Have you tried putting an extra whiteline between the tab header and the code chunk? (that has worked for me once)

Comment: @teunbrand yes, I just tried it again but tabs are still missing.  Thanks though, I know that does work sometimes but not here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I wrapped the call to ggplotly(), the graphs are displayed.

```
barplot_group_count <- ggplot(data=group_count, aes(x=Group, y=n)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = "Count of Groups According to PSA Attributes") +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(2, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5),"cm"))+
  coord_flip()

ggplotly(barplot_group_count)
```